# why does sgi stl source code use the double-colon in front of the operator new function?

Tags: c++, stl

I am reading the source code of SGI standard template library. I find that the `operator new` function always has a double-colon in front of it. Like this:

```
T* tmp = (T*)(::operator new((size_t)(size * sizeof(T))));
```

`operator new` can be directly called without adding the `::` field, then why do the stl coders write it in this way? What trap or situation may it come to if we don't use the `::` in front of them.

Comment: No one worked on that code for over a decade... its not really a good read.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can overload operator new for a class and prefixing it with "::" will call the global "default" operator new instead of a possible overload. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
  Foo() { std::cout << "Foo::Foo()" << std::endl; }

  void * operator new(size_t )
  { 
    std::cout << "Foo::operator new()" << std::endl; 
    return static_cast<Foo *>(malloc(sizeof(Foo)));
  }
};


int main()
{
  Foo foo;
  std::cout << "----------------------" << std::endl;
  Foo * p = new Foo;
  std::cout << "----------------------" << std::endl;
  Foo * q = ::new Foo;
}
```

will print

```
Foo::Foo()
----------------------
Foo::operator new()
Foo::Foo()
----------------------
Foo::Foo()
```

Edit: The code snipped is indeed *not* about operator new that is defined in a class scope. A better example would be this:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace quux {

void * operator new(size_t s)
{
  std::cout << "quux::operator new" << std::endl;
  return malloc(s);
}

void foo()
{
  std::cout << "quux::foo()" << std::endl;
  int * p = static_cast<int*>(operator new(sizeof(int)));
}

void bar()
{
  std::cout << "quux::bar()" << std::endl;
  int * p = static_cast<int*>(::operator new(sizeof(int)));
}

} // namespace quux


int main()
{
  quux::foo();
  quux::bar();
}
```

which prints

```
quux::foo()
quux::operator new
quux::bar()
```

Comment: -1: It's not what is used in the code. The code shown is calling the raw memory allocator, not an object allocator.

Answer (score 1):

`::operator new` in C++ is the global memory allocator that is called every time a certain amount of bytes is needed for a single object. Note that the return value is a `void *` and that `::operator new(size_t)` deals with raw bytes, not objects.

It is basically the C++ counterpart of `malloc` with simply a funny name.

A separate global allocator `::operator new[](size_t sz)` is instead used to allocate memory for arrays of objects.

These two operators, their counterparts `::operator delete` and `::operator delete[]` and also the `nothrow` version of the allocators are used for all memory needs of the C++ runtime.

They may be implemented in terms of calls to `malloc`/`free` or not. What is guaranteed is that `malloc` and `free` dont use them (thus you can call `malloc` and `free` if you want to reimplement these functions without the risk of infinite recursion).

Comment: True, but that doesn't explain why the `::` is there, which is the core of the question.

Comment: @AngeW: `::operator new` is the name of the global allocator. Think to `::` as "global" and read it as "global operator new". Note that `::operator new (size_t)` (what is used in the shown code) has **nothing** to do with class custom allocators that other answers are talking about.

Comment: I know what a leading `::` means. Nevertheless, you could just as well refer to that function just as `operator new`. That's why I think your answer should explain why the `::` is there.

Answer (score 0):

> Double-colon is used to prevent T::operator new() to be called (if
>   defined).

Comment: No: `::operator new (size_t)` is a raw memory allocator and has nothing to do with custom class allocators (except a similarity in the name).

Answer (score 0):

To call the `operator new` from the global namespace, in case the user (or someone) else decided to have a `new` operator.